# How can I connect an App to Thingspeak?

Tags: android

How can we connect an Android App to Thingspeak to retrieve data stored in the cloud?The data should be displayed as a graph in the application

Answer (score 1):

ThingSpeak provides an API to read channel data. You would construct a URL that includes your channel ID and the number of points that you want to return. The API returns JSON formatted data. Your app would iterate through the returned data and build a chart.

Documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/readdata.html

Example: https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/266256/feeds.json

If your channel is private, you will also need to provide a Read API Key.